# Expecting element 'CustomerLeads' from namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

Im getting the following error when running my application: Additional information: Error in line 2 position 64. Expecting element 'CustomerLeads' from namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'CustomerLeads', namespace ''.

I dont understand why I am getting this error message because as you can see from the XML 'CustomerLeads' is included within the XML. If I take out the namespace the file will not read the Elements. Including the namespace seems to work but cant seem to figure out why I am getting this error. And how I can add the namespace without getting this error?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomerLeads xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BasicCustomerLead.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CustomerLead>
    <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <Email>psmith@example.com</Email>
  </CustomerLead>-<CustomerLead>
    <FirstName>Nicole</FirstName>
    <LastName>Farhi</LastName>
    <Email>nicole.farhi@example.com</Email>
  </CustomerLead>-<CustomerLead>
    <FirstName>Raf</FirstName>
    <LastName>Simons</LastName>
    <Email>rafs@example.org</Email>
  </CustomerLead>
</CustomerLeads>
```

Code:

```
namespace Customer
{
    [DataContract(Name = "CustomerLeads", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public class CustomerLeads
    {

        [DataMember()]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [DataMember()]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }


        public CustomerLeads unSortedLeads(string xmFilelPath)
        {

            // doc.Load("C:/Users/Admin/Downloads/potentialcustomers.xml");


            ICollection<CustomerLeads> deserializedPerson;
            CustomerLeads lead;

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(xmFilelPath, FileMode.Open);
            XmlDictionaryReader reader = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(fs, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
            DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(CustomerLeads));


            lead = (CustomerLeads)ser.ReadObject(reader, true);
            reader.Close();
            fs.Close();

            FirstName = lead.FirstName.ToString();

            // foreach(CustomerLeads leads in deserializedPerson.)

            return lead;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might try `<xsi:CustomerLeads>` xsi being the xml namespace. Seems like the error is saying it doesn't know what namespace CustomerLeads belongs to.

```
<xsi:CustomerLeads xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="BasicCustomerLead.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CustomerLead>
    <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <Email>psmith@example.com</Email>
  </CustomerLead>-<CustomerLead>
    <FirstName>Nicole</FirstName>
    <LastName>Farhi</LastName>
    <Email>nicole.farhi@example.com</Email>
  </CustomerLead>-<CustomerLead>
    <FirstName>Raf</FirstName>
    <LastName>Simons</LastName>
    <Email>rafs@example.org</Email>
  </CustomerLead>
</xsi:CustomerLeads>
```

The prefix might be required for the other elements as well.

Comment: Ive tried adding "CustomerLeads" to the "Namespace" on "DataContract"  but still giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataContract` attribute asserts that the `CustomerLeads` element is expected to be in the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` XML namespace.  It is not.  In your XML, `CustomerLeads` has no namespace (effectively an empty namespace).

Try removing the `Namespace` setting from your `DataContract` attribute.

Comment: I still get the following error: Additional information: Error in line 1 position 70. Expecting element 'CustomerLeads' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Customer'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'CustomerLeads', namespace ''.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you need to set `Namespace = ""` in your `DataContract` attribute (or, alternatively, add `xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Customer"` to your `CustomerLeads` XML element).  It looks like it's cooking up a namespace for you instead of expecting an empty namespace by default.

Comment: Ive tried both. with the first solution `XmlDictionaryReader reader` doesn't read any of the elements (where as with the namespace included it did) the second solution generates the same error message above just with the extra namespace included in the error

Comment: Does the schema in `BasicCustomerLead.xsd` declare a `targetNamespace`?  If so, try specifying _that_ namespace on your `DataContract` attribute.

Comment: I dont have access to the BasicCustomerLead.xsd schema. Maybe I am approaching this wrong? I need to return a list of customerLead objects from each XML element.

Comment: What happens if you remove all the attributes on the `CustomerLeads` element and set `Namespace = ""` on your `DataContract` (or leave it off entirely)?  XML namespaces are such a tremendous pain.

Comment: It reads when I change the `DataContract` to `CustomerLead` But then Produces the same error even if I take the `namespace` from `DataContract`. When I Change the `Namespace`="" it doesn't return with an error but then the `DataContractSerializer` doesn't read the Element.

Comment: Wait a minute... your `DataContract` attribute has an element name of `CustomerLeads` (plural), but its members describe a single `CustomerLead`.  What happens if you replace the XML with a single `CustomerLead` element and also change the `DataContract` element name to `CustomerLead`?